# What is the best/easiest way to process received email message body and resend it?

Tags: email, automation, email-client

I am receiving chart data in JSON format to my email address and my goal is to convert it to chart/chart img and resend it to my email address.

I have been looking for several methods:

- Google App script used for gmail. *I failed to find trigger on newly received message.*
- Email client, that supports adding actions based on scripts to new incoming message trigger. *Only one I know about is MS Outlook with VBA scripts, but creating chart image with lack of libraries available in VBA is not very elegant solution.*
- Open source email client with possibility to alter the code and so directly process data and resend message.  *The more robust email client, the harder is to change the code to do relatively simple job, I believe.*

I really don´t know what kind of solution this simple problem needs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are interested in some kind of gateway on the server side, not client-side. Take a closer look at your server-side implementation. For example, you may start from the [Mail flow rules (transport rules) in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/mail-flow-rules) page.

Comment: I do believe, that if client is able to communicate with the server and retrieve new messages, display them as new unseen, display their content,  it´s also able to do actions with them as parse email text end resend it.